# How to generate customized primary key generating in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, primary-key

I need to create a primary key as Banner1, Banner2, Banner_3... For that I'm using org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator .  Below I have attached the relevant code.

```
package com.websafe.ccmsbe.entity;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.MappingException;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SharedSessionContractImplementor;
import org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator;
import org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.ConfigurationHelper;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.type.LongType;
import org.hibernate.type.Type;

import java.util.Properties;

public class StringPrefixedSequenceGenerator extends SequenceStyleGenerator {

    public static final String VALUE_PREFIX_PARAMETER = "valuePrefix";
    public static final String VALUE_PREFIX_DEFAULT = "";
    private String valuePrefix;

    public static final String NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER = "numberFormat";
    public static final String NUMBER_FORMAT_DEFAULT = "%d";
    private String numberFormat;
    @Override
    public void configure(Type type, Properties params, ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) throws MappingException {
        super.configure(LongType.INSTANCE, params, serviceRegistry);
        valuePrefix = ConfigurationHelper.getString(VALUE_PREFIX_PARAMETER, params, VALUE_PREFIX_DEFAULT);
        numberFormat = ConfigurationHelper.getString(NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER, params, NUMBER_FORMAT_DEFAULT);
    }

    @Override
    public Object generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object object) throws HibernateException {
        return valuePrefix + String.format(numberFormat, super.generate(session, object));
    }
}
```

The problem occurs in configure method.

valuePrefix = ConfigurationHelper.getString(VALUE_PREFIX_PARAMETER, params, VALUE_PREFIX_DEFAULT);
numberFormat = ConfigurationHelper.getString(NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER, params, NUMBER_FORMAT_DEFAULT);

In this both lines ConfigurationHelper.getString() method doesn;t work. It displays "No candidates found for the method call". Can anyone please help me to resolve this?

I have attached the relevant entity class also below.

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity(name = "CookieBanner")
@Table(name = "cookie_banner")
public class CookieBanner {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator ="banner_seq",strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
   @GenericGenerator(name = "banner_seq",strategy = "com.websafe.ccmsbe.entity.StringPrefixedSequenceGenerator",parameters = {
           @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = StringPrefixedSequenceGenerator.INCREMENT_PARAM,value = "1"),
           @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = StringPrefixedSequenceGenerator.VALUE_PREFIX_PARAMETER, value = "Banner_"),
           @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = StringPrefixedSequenceGenerator.NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER,value = "%05d")
   })
    @Column(name = "banner_id")
    private String bannerId;
    private String bannerPosition;
    private String bannerColor;
    private String bannerAlignment;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(
            name = "website_id",
            referencedColumnName = "websiteId",
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_website_id_cb")
    )
    private Website website;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "cookieBanner"
    )
    private List<CookieBannerTemplate> cookieBannerTemplates = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

I tried changing the version number of hibernate in the pom.xml . but it didn't work. Current version I;m using is

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
   <version>5.6.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```